# Uploading files and strings to a php server

Tags: php, android, file-upload, forms, http-post

I want to upload files and strings to a HTML form on PHP server. I uploaded files with below code but I don't know how to upload string. How should I modify this code to upload strings to text fields of the form?
My HTML form:

```
    <form name="form" id="gallery" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="send_1.php">
<div id="contain" >
        <div class='file_browse_wrapper' id="file1">
            <input type="file" size="32" name="file1" value=""  />
            <input type="file" size="32" name="file2" value=""  />           
            <input type="text" size="32" name="phonenumber" value="1234" />
            <input type="text" size="32" name="uploadmessage" value="some text" />
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="click me" /><!--end add-->
</form><!--end form-->
```

I was able to upload files with this code:

```
 public int uploadFiles(int pictureNumber, String strToUpload1, String strToUpload2) {
     String uploadServerUri;
     String uploadFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Pictures/MyCameraApp/";
     final int timeStamp;
     int serverResponseCode = 0;
     HttpURLConnection conn = null;
     int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
     byte[] buffer;
     int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
     String lineEnd = "\r\n";
     String twoHyphens = "--";
     String boundary = "*****";
     DataOutputStream doc = null;
     FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
     String[] paths = new String[2];

     for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
         paths[i] = uploadFilePath + timeStamp +"-" + Integer.toString( pictureNumber + i ) + ".jpg" ;
      }
      try {
          URL url = new URL(uploadServerUri);
          conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
          conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
          conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
          conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
          conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
          conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
          conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
          for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
              conn.setRequestProperty("uploadedfile" + Integer.toString(i), paths[i]);
          for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
              File sourceFile = new File(paths[i]);
              fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
              Log.d(TAG, ".....start uploading file"+ Integer.toString(i));
              doc = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
              doc.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
              doc.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile" + (i + 1) + "\"" + ";filename=\""
                      + paths[i] + "\"" + lineEnd);
              doc.writeBytes(lineEnd);
              // create a buffer of  maximum size
              bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
              bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
              buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
              // read file and write it into form...
              bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              while (bytesRead > 0) {
                  doc.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                  bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                  bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
              }
              // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
              doc.writeBytes(lineEnd);
              doc.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);      
              Log.d(TAG, ".....upload file "+Integer.toString(i)+" completed");
              fileInputStream.close();
              doc.flush();
          }//end of for
          // Responses from the server (code and message)
          serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
          String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
          Log.d(TAG, "HTTP Response is : "
                  + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
          if(serverResponseCode == 200)
              Log.d(TAG, "upload completed");
          doc.close();
      }//end of first try
      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage().toString()+"..."+"MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage().toString());
      }
      return serverResponseCode;      

}
```

Comment: why is there HTML involved with this

Comment: to showing form fields

Comment: HTML has got nothing to do with your requirement or the problem

Comment: You need to post the variable to send_1.php directly from android

Comment: @sistyN the HTML form is for a webpage, your app would be "the form" in this case, and you should post directly to `send_1.php`

Comment: I uploaded files without problem to my PHP server, I want to know how can I upload strings ?

Comment: you can directly upload strings from android client to php server by using json parsing

Comment: have you successfully get the values from html form in android (client side)?